# How to combine two similar methods in java?

Tags: java

I have two methods, they are different in their conditions. So how I can combine two methods into one?

```
private void filterById(String keyW) {
    neModel.setRowCount(0);
    for (int i = neList.size() - 1; i > -1; i--) {
        //CONDITION:
        if (String.valueOf(neList.get(i).getId()).toLowerCase().contains(keyW.toLowerCase())) {
            Object[] aRow = createARow(i);
            neModel.addRow(aRow);
        }
    }
}

private void filterByTitle(String keyW) {
    neModel.setRowCount(0);
    for (int i = neList.size() - 1; i > -1; i--) {
        //CONDITION:
        if (neList.get(i).getTitle().toLowerCase().contains(keyW.toLowerCase())) {
            Object[] aRow = createARow(i);
            neModel.addRow(aRow);
        }
    }
}
```

*'neList' ia an ArrayList of 'News'
. Class 'News' has properties: id, title, text, etc.

Comment: You could try to use a functional interface and pass the differences as a strategy.

Comment: combine if statements with `||`

Comment: @Spara, use || can filter multiple columns, but I would like to filter for only one column

Comment: I don't see much incentive to do this.  Sure, the methods look *similar*, but I don't see any benefit to combining these two methods into one since their business logic is still *quite* different.  Can you justify *why* you want to do this?

Comment: @Makoto, because my teacher does not want to look similar code, :). Just for joke, actually, I have 7 methods like that

Comment: Could you priove what exactly returns `neList`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With Java 8+, you could try to use a functional interface and pass the differences as a strategy.

Something like this (untested as I don't have a compiler atm):

```
private void filter(String keyW, Function<News, String> propertyExtractor) {
  neModel.setRowCount(0);

  //note that this could probably be replaced by for(News news : newList)
  //but in that case you'd either have to change createARow to not need the index or increment the index in the loop body
  for (int i = neList.size() - 1; i > -1; i--) {        
    if (propertyExtractor.apply(neList.get(i)).toLowerCase().contains(keyW.toLowerCase())) {
        Object[] aRow = createARow(i);
        neModel.addRow(aRow);
    }
  }
}

//Examples of how to use it, you don't have to keep those (delegating) methods
private void filterById(String keyW) { 
  filter( keyW, e -> String.valueOf(e.getId()));
}

private void filterByTitle(String keyW) { 
  filter( keyW, News::getTitle);
  //or: filter( keyW, e -> e.getTitle());
}
```

Alternatively instead of a `Function<T, S>` pass in a `Predicate<T>` which provides the entire condition and just do `if(predicate.test(neList.get(i))) { ... }`.

**Edit**: replaced `T` with `News` as per the OP's comment

Comment: @Aomine No, both will work. Using a predicate, you'd have to include the to-lowercase and contains-stuff also in the predicate, and thus repeat it for each filter. This way, it is in the common part.

Comment: @tobias_k I see it now, the method call of `apply` ends here `propertyExtractor.apply(neList.get(i))` the parentheses confused me.

Comment: type of 'neList' is: ArrayList<News>. 'News' is a designed class

Comment: @tobias_k that would be true for `getTitle` (I didn't want to introduce yet another unfamiliar syntax though ;) ) - but  `String.valueOf(e.getId())` indicates  `getId()` returns something else.

Comment: @Thomas You are right, somehow I totally missed the `String.valueOf`....

Answer (score 3):

And if you can't yet use Java 8 features, you can simply define an `enum`:

```
enum Filter {
    ById,
    ByTitle
}
```

And then pass it as a flag:

```
private void filter(Filter how, String keyW) {
    neModel.setRowCount(0);
    for (int i = neList.size() - 1; i > -1; i--) {
        String value;
        switch (how) {
        case ById:
            value = String.valueOf(neList.get(i).getId());
            break;
        // ... add more cases here ...
        default:
            value = neList.get(i).getTitle();
            break;
        }
        //CONDITION:
        if (value.toLowerCase().contains(keyW.toLowerCase())) {
            Object[] aRow = createARow(i);
            neModel.addRow(aRow);
        }
    }
}
```

Example invocation:

```
    x.filter(Filter.ById, "");
    x.filter(Filter.ByTitle, "");
```

Comment: Why not give the filter enum the filter function a method?

Comment: I can see that there are more operators which are to catch 'how', sr but I do not expect that. I expect shorter code, but the number of operators should not be increased. by the way, Thank you for suggestion!

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use functional parameters you can just create 1 method with an extra parameter corresponding to the desired procedure.  
This extra parameter could be an **enum** or if there are only two cases 1 **boolean flag**:

```
private void filterBy(boolean byId, String keyW) {
    neModel.setRowCount(0);
    for (int i = neList.size() - 1; i > -1; i--) {
        String what = byId ? String.valueOf(neList.get(i).getId()) : neList.get(i).getTitle();

        if (what.toLowerCase().contains(keyW.toLowerCase())) {
            Object[] aRow = createARow(i);
            neModel.addRow(aRow);
        }
    }
}
```

Now call it like this:

```
filterBy(true, yourkey) // instead of filterById(yourkey)
```

or

```
filterBy(false, yourkey) // instead of filterByTitle(yourkey)
```

Comment: Actually, I have 7 method like that

Comment: Then enum it is.

Comment: Or if you find it easier just an integer value

Answer (score 0):

```
public void filterBy(String keyW, Function<Data, String> function) {
    String key = keyW.toLowerCase();
    neModel.setRowCount(0);

    IntStream.range(0, neList.size())
             .mapToObj(i -> function.apply(neList.get(neList.size() - i - 1)).toLowerCase().contains(key) ? createARow(i) : null)
             .filter(Objects::nonNull)
             .forEach(row -> neModel.addRow(row));
}
```

Answer (score -2):

You can put || (OR) operator between conditions in same if.

If indexes conflicts take one more index variable to manage.

Comment: You means I need indexes for filterById, filterByTitle. but there will be more operators for managing

Comment: Actually I'm talking about 'i'. If it changes in the process then that might affect the way code executes.